# How can I fix inversion of light and shade of normal map?

Tags: normal-map

I made a normal map of cloth by bake and set it to low-polygon object. Then I checked it on render view, the light and shade of cloth had  inverted between front and back.

But I can't find what probrem is and I can't fix it though tried to.

Could you give me some advise. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share the shirt (with the images packed into the file)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Start from changing in your texture node the color space from sRGB to "Non-Color", with the strenght set to 1.0, and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: Oh, as you say I could solve this problem with changing color space! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments!